# What is the faster way to save and browse objects using vectors +/or maps? (c++)

Tags: object-oriented, c++, data-structures, data, class

I'm doing a object Garbage class using c++:

```
#include "Object.h"

class ObjectGarbage
{
   public:
      ObjectGarbage();
      ~ObjectGarbage();

      void Call_All_Objects()
      {
          //(some for loops) {Garbage[..][..][i].Main(); }
      }
      void GetObject(Object *obj)
      {
          //Data type get (obj)
      }

   private:
   //Object Data
}
```

The class object is a base class of many others like actors, HUDs...
I need to find some way to divide and save the objects for easier access.

I decided to make the first division of data by Layers (When drawing). Then i would divide them by the name of the specific class like the HUD,Actor,... and then subdivide them by the name of the instances like Actor1, Actor2, Actor3...

How can i make these divisions as fast as it can be to access?
Maybe something like this:

```
vector<map<string, map<string, Object*>>>
//(Layer as vector -> Specific Class Name as Map -> Name of the Instance as map too)
```

I never tried something like this and i don't know how to use it properly either. So how can i? Are there better ways?

Comment: I don't understand what your code is trying to do.  A method named `Call_All_Objects` should have a simple one dimensional iterable collection to traverse (thinking of list) unless there is a darn good reason to make it more complicated.  Your `GetObject` doesn't seem to get anything since it doesn't return anything.  You're clearly thinking of a more complicated data structure but you haven't justified any reason why. You've only stated decisions made. There are good reasons to make complicated ones.  What are yours?  If it helps take a look at this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G70oT.png

Comment: Thx for the replay and the amazing image.  The getobject is just an empty function for trying to show what i want to do. In some cases of my code i am going to want to find some particular  object instances or group (the class) saved on the object garbage so i thought i could make divisions like that to make it easier to implement and faster to run. Or i am complicating a thing that could be easier?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't showing what you want to do. I can see a way to send some "call" message to all objects. I can see a way to pass an object that is supposed "get" an object somehow. Other than that I have no idea what I'd ever use an `ObjectGarbage` class for.  I don't know what the point of these divisions is.  Give me a use case.  Tell me a story.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?  All I know is it's a base class for other classes that I also don't know what you're doing with.  Help me out here.

Comment: Until I know what you're trying to do I can't tell if this is too complicated or not complicated enough.  The needs you are expressing: save, lookup, and speed are basic needs of any collection / data structure.  If you want to improve on them in some way your best bet is to at least have some specific use in mind.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you without knowing what your underlying requirement us. We see the code but it doesn't seem to match any obvious requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advice 1: Consider using [`std::unordered_map` (explanation on en.cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if you need fast lookup and don't need sorting by key. In C++, `std::unordered_map` is an implementation of the hash table that you have learned from the "data structures and algorithms" class. On the other hand, `std::map` is a balanced binary search tree.

Advice 2: Given a multi-level data structure, if the first few levels are relatively stable (i.e. there will not be any insertions into or deletions from the first one or two levels), it is possible to concatenate the keys for those levels and use them as a key in either `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Advice 3: String hashing takes time. If you are building a game engine, you may want to preprocess the game design entered by the game engine's user, in order to assign all string keys into unique integers. This will reduce the hashing overhead when the game engine is executing. For example, if game engine's user has designed a game involving three fruits and three animals, you can assign a unique integer to each string: "apple" = 1, "banana" = 2, "cantaloupe" = 3, "donkey" = 4, "elephant" = 5, "fox" = 6. This string-to-integer mapping can occur ahead-of-time.

Advice 4: If there is a need to look up objects using more than one properties, consider learning about [Boost Multi-index (www.boost.org)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). At the minimum, read through the introduction and the diagrams to understand how to approach the problem.

Advice 5: As you are designing a game engine, you may eventually discover some hidden pitfalls of nesting STL containers. To break the nesting, you may need to use some pointers. Smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` might be useful.

Finally, the design problem you are facing may be too difficult or too large to be explained clearly. In this cases, you probably will not get any useful answer on any forum on the internet. Consider partnering with someone who is more experienced in the programming language and/or game engine design.

Comment: Thx so much! I just didn't understand the part of assigning an int to a string. It is supposed to make something like this:?  #define apple 1, #define banana 2 .........  string apple = apple; string banana = banana; And the boost Multi-index looks interesting! I will give it a look!

Comment: @AndreMarques: You can ignore that part for now. It only makes sense if the game design (i.e. the strings) exist as data files. If the user of the game engine is going to program directly in C++ using your game engine, the user will be responsible for the performance issues resulting from using strings as identifiers.